# Pointer precedence and dereferring in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct student{
    int age;
    char *name;
};
struct student b[3] = { 30, "Peter", 40, "Mary", 50, "John" };
struct student *p = b;



int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", ++p->age);
    printf("%s\n", (*p).name);
    printf("%c\n", *p->name-1);
    printf("%c\n", *++p->name);
    printf("%c\n", *p++->name);
    printf("%c\n", *(++p)->name);
}
```

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how each of the statement work, could anyone give a break down of what was done?

1: `++p->age` isn't it suppose to be increase `p` and then access the member `age`?

Comment: "*For ++p->age isn't it suppose to be increase p and then access the member age?*" No. `p->age` is executed first

Comment: Reading this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence might help.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d\n", ++p->age);
```

`p->age` is executed first. Then, the prefix increment operator(`++`) increases the value by one and this value is printed(`31`).

```
printf("%s\n", (*p).name);
```

Here, `(*p).name` is the same as `p->name`. This prints `Peter`.

```
printf("%c\n", *p->name-1);
```

Firstly, `p->name` executes which gives `Peter`. Applying the dereference operator gives the first character of `Peter` which is `P`. Subtracting one from `P` gives us `O` and this is the character that gets printed.

```
printf("%c\n", *++p->name);
```

Here, `p->name` executes first and gives `Peter`. When this is incremented, it gives `eter`. When the dereference operator is applyed, we get the first character of `eter` which is `e`. This is the character that gets printed.

```
printf("%c\n", *p++->name);
```

Here, `++` gets executed first. Since it is the postfix increment operator, the original value is returned. Then, `->` executes and this gives us `eter`(Since it was already incremented in the previous `printf`). When the `*` operator is applyed here, we get `e`. This is printed.

```
printf("%c\n", *(++p)->name);
```

Here, `p` is incremented. Now, it points to `b[2]`(It was incremented once in the previous `printf`). Then, `->` executes which gives `John`. Applying the `*` operator, we get `J` and this is printed.

Reading about [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) would be handy.